# Converting xlxs file to csv

Tags: excel, bash, shell, scripting

I have *N* number of sheets in an excel file. now I want to convert all of the sheets into `.csv` format Using bash shell scripting And before converting the `xlxs` file to `.csv` I need to add extra columns to each sheet with common value at the end. Please help

Comment: why don't you use the internal `.vb` script of Excel to export your file. Doing this in `bash` will not be easy (by comparison). Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other comment, can't this be done through excel?

Example solution if you choose this approach:

```
' Forces all variables to be declared
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()

' Define variable types
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim currentWorkSheet As String
Dim PathName As String

' Stop screen from flickering while code is running
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop.
For I = 1 To WS_Count

   ' Find name of the current sheet
   currentWorkSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

   ' Go to the current sheet
   Worksheets(currentWorkSheet).Activate

   ' Add extra column on that sheet

   ' Select rows in the extra column where the formula is to be added
   Range("D1:D10").Select

   ' Add the formula (example formula, multiplying previous column by 1)
   Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*1"

   ' Export to CSV

   ' Copy the current worksheet
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentWorkSheet).Copy after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(currentWorkSheet)

   ' Rename the current worksheet
   Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Name = currentWorkSheet & "_export"

   ' Export the excel to csv

   ' Create path and name for export
   PathName = "" & ThisWorkbook.Path & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"

   ' Move sheet to seperate workbook
   Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Move

   ' Save as CSV file
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, FileFormat:=xlCSV

   ' Close that CSV with the SAVE warnings surpressed
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

To run the code use the vba editor (shortcut to open the editor ALT+F11). Open a new macro, paste the code, then you can use F8 to step through each line

Comment: Any clues as to where you put this code and how you make it run?

Comment: sure, open the vba editor (ALT+F11) in excel, create a new module, then run it from there. F8 allows you to step through the code line by line

Comment: Cool, thank you - I only ask because some folks don't do this stuff every day and it kind of helps to get people started and having a try and learning that they can do stuff. Good answer too, thank you.